# Node Js 8.11 постоянные ошибки getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

Tags: node.js, request

Пишу сервис с большим количеством https запросов и постоянно возникает ошибка на getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN вот полный текст ошибки

```
getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN yobit.net:443',
  jse_cause: 
   { Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN yobit.net:443
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
     code: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     errno: 'EAI_AGAIN',
     syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
     hostname: 'yobit.net',
     host: 'yobit.net',
     port: 443 }
```

При профилировании скрипта показывает, что 98% времени приложение просто ждет. Скажите у кого-то была подобная проблема? если да то как решили ?

Comment: Ошибка говорит о невозможности забрать данные с yobit.net. Зайдя на сам yobit.net я вижу, что он использует cloudflare, как защиту от ддоса и иже. Рекомендую добавить в запрос хедеры браузеров, что бы yobit думал, что это к нему браузер заходит, а не парсер левый

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на вопрос. Проблема была в модуле request в его настройках по умолчанию. Изменив их получил нужный результат

```
const request=require('request');
request.defaults({pool:{
        maxSockets: Infinity
    }});
```